# How to register middlware with illuminate/routing standalone package?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Docs say to register middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`. How do I register middleware outside of the framework?

Comment: Why would you say it's outside the framework?

Comment: what I mean is I am not using the whole framework, but just the routing component in a non-laravel application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by outside of the framework but it pretty much comes down to this:

```
// Get your Illuminate\Routing\Router from somewhere.
// This could either be from the container instance or
// an instance you instantiated yourself somewhere
$router = new Illuminate\Routing\Router(....
// or in case you plan on doing this in a service provider for example
$router = $this->app['router'];

// Now you add your middleware using the following syntax
$router->middleware('name', My\Middleware::class);

// It's also possible to add a middleware group
$router->middlewareGroup('group_name', [
    'name',
    My\Other\Middleware::class
]);

// It's also possible to do this using the Laravel Facade's
Route::middleware(...
Route::middlewareGroup(...
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thanks! Btw, I also figured out that I could use the full name of the class when assigning middleware to the route, i.e. `Route::group(['middleware' => \My\Middleware::class], function () { ...`. The usage of aliases throughout the documentation confused me here.

Comment: Awesome, did not know that either! :)